# Cannot use Texture passed to a base class?

Tags: c#, xna

Alright guys, so I've got a GameObject class and I inherited it to my Player class.
So I've done this in the constructor:

```
 public Player(Vector2 position, Texture2D tex):base(position,tex)
    {
    }
```

Now, I have a Draw method, and I need the Texture to use the Draw method.
But because I used the Texture from the GameObject class I can't use the texture in this method.
What can I do about it?
Leave a comment if you didn't understand anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should post a snippet of your *GameObject* class. Using my psychic abilities, I reckon your Texture object is declared as private in *GameObject*. Change it to *protected* like this:

```
class GameObject
{
    protected Texture2D _texture;
    public GameObject(Vector2 position, Texture2D tex)
    {
        ...
        _texture = tex;
    }
}

class Player : GameObject
{
    public Player(Vector2 position, Texture2D tex):base(position,tex)
    {
    }

    public override void Draw(...)
    {
        // _texture should be accessible from here.
    }
}
```

Read [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to learn more about using private, protected, etc.

Answer (score 2):

How is `GameObject` storing `tex`? The field it's being set to may not be accessible from the derived class `Player`. Try changing it's access modified to `protected` if this is the case.

Comment: But that's not my problem, It's pretty general question, not about XNA. If I'm using the base constructor. I can't use the variables that I did with the :base on the other methods, so I'm asking,

Comment: @Kulbai Khan How can I use these variables that I inherited from the base class in other methods such as the position,rotation and such.

Comment: @Joey this is a pretty general answer, and I know nothing about XNA. It sounds like this is what you need to do but I need more information. Is the `Texture2d` being set to a field in `GameObject`? If so, what is the access to that field? If it's `private` (or nothing at all, which means `private`) try setting it to `protected`. That will allow `Player` to see it.

Comment: Thanks alot, it was actually the answer and I messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared the `_texture` member as protected?

```
public abstract class GameObject
{
  protected Texture2D _texture;

  public GameObject(Texture2D tex) { 
    _texture = tex;
  }

  public abstract void Draw();
}

public class Player : GameObject
{
  public Player(Texture2D tex) : base (tex) { }

  public override Draw()
  {
     //Do stuff with _texture.
  }
}
```